# Matplotlib 3D bar plot displaying empty 3D space for one graph but not another

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I have separated my data into small and larger numbers, and I want to plot two separate bar graphs, however only one graph prints. If I comment out the second plot, the code returns an empty plot like this:
[image: :]

Below is a reproducible pandas data frame along with my code that I'm using with my second plot commented out.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Ionization #': [4.341, 5.139, 5.212, 5.986, 6.108],
                   'Name': ['Potassium', 'Sodium', 'Barium', 'Aluminium', 'Thalium'],
                   'Nebulizer 1': [27.0923, 23.1222, 0.1975, 5.0517, 0.1484],
                   'Nebulizer 2': [18.5475, 21.1542, 0.0721, 3.9544, 0.3125],
                   'Nebulizer 3': [25.2555, 20.5644, 0.1665, 0.3125, 0.0154]})

# Seperating the large values from the small values, and putting them in separate data frames
micro_df = df.loc[df['Nebulizer 1'] + df['Nebulizer 2'] + df['Nebulizer 2'] < 3]
macro_df = df.loc[df['Nebulizer 1'] + df['Nebulizer 2'] + df['Nebulizer 3'] >= 3]
    
# isolating the numerical values I want
MDL_micro = micro_df[['Nebulizer 1', 'Nebulizer 2', 'Nebulizer 3']]
MDL_macro = macro_df[['Nebulizer 1', 'Nebulizer 2', 'Nebulizer 3']]
    
# putting values into a numpy array  
dz_micro = MDL_micro.values.ravel()
dz_macro = MDL_macro.values.ravel()
    
# bar width
dy, dx = 0.5, 0.5

# setup the figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax1 = Axes3D(fig)
ax2 = Axes3D(fig)

# set position for bars
ypos_mac = np.arange(3)
ypos_mic = np.arange(2)
xpos_mac = np.arange(3)
xpos_mic = np.arange(3)

#set the ticks in the middle of the bars
ax1.set_xticks(xpos_mac + dx/2)
ax1.set_yticks(ypos_mac + dy/2)

ax2.set_xticks(xpos_mic + dx/2)
ax2.set_yticks(ypos_mic + dy/2)

# create mesh grid ax1 and ax2
xpos_mac, ypos_mac = np.meshgrid(xpos_mac, ypos_mac)
xpos_mac = xpos_mac.flatten()
ypos_mac = ypos_mac.flatten()

xpos_mic, ypos_mic = np.meshgrid(xpos_mic, ypos_mic)
xpos_mic = xpos_mic.flatten()
ypos_mic = ypos_mic.flatten()

# the bars start from 0k
zpos_mac = np.zeros(9, dtype=int).flatten()
zpos_mic = np.zeros(6, dtype=int).flatten()

# first 3d plot
ax1.bar3d(xpos_mac, ypos_mac, zpos_mac, dx, dy, dz_macro)

ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(MDL_macro.columns, fontsize=8)
ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(macro_df['Name'], fontsize=6)

# second 3d plot
# ax2.bar3d(xpos_mic, ypos_mic, zpos_mic, dx, dy, dz_micro)
#
# ax2.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(MDL_micro.columns, fontsize=8)
# ax2.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(micro_df['Name'], fontsize=6)

#Axis Labels
ax1.set_xlabel('Nebulizer')
ax1.set_ylabel('Element')
ax1.set_zlabel('MDL')

ax2.set_xlabel('Nebulizer')
ax2.set_ylabel('Element')
ax2.set_zlabel('MDL')

plt.show()
```

I have checked the contents of the arrays that I am using, so I know its not that.

Comment: An empty plot is correct. From the code you've posted no data is being used by the ax object (ax2) - in fact, it's commented out. Matplotlib only shows a blank graph when no data is available to display.

Comment: Do you want subplots (side by side)?

Comment: @jrd1 I know ax2 is commented out, I did that in order to trouble shoot why I am getting no result for ax1. From what I can see, I do have data in ax1, and ax1 is still printing an empty space. If I un-comment out ax2 it only prints the second plot.

Comment: @BigBen that would be nice as well, currently I am just trying to get my first plot to show the data that is in the argument.

Comment: Change `ax1 = Axes3D(fig)` to `ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')` and `ax2 = Axes3D(fig)` to `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')` for example.

Comment: @BigBen Ok that worked thank you! I didn't know you had to plot them side by side in order to view both. My problem was from not commenting out all the 'ax2' code